# Kit-ops: how are cutters done?

Tags: selection-tools, data-blocks

I was looking at the free version of Kit-ops plug-in, and I noticed that the selection of a single component of the cutter, selects all the element of the cutter. This happens both in the 3d view and in the outliner.

It looks like all the elements are grouped, but I don't understand how it is done. There is parenting, but even removing the parent the selection works as before. Also, parented objects can not be selected that way.

I also noticed that the main object has a number of user data corresponding to the "child" objects, but the data-block is at object level, not mesh level. Maybe this is the reason, but I don't have any idea on how to do that.

In this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qgzC.jpg), after selecting ADV Cube3 1 cube 002, ADV Cube3 1 plane is selected as well.
Also, ADV Cube3 1 plane has 3 users

Any hint or explanation on how this is done would be much appreciated.

Thank you,

Luca

Comment: Hello and welcome. I'd recommend to ask the author of the addon, usually they have even Youtube channels that might already go through what you asked. And since there is a paid version with the functionality to create your own inserts, i think it's better to first check there. [kit-ops.com/support](https://www.kit-ops.com/support) may also be a reasonable place to look at.

Answer (score 1):

After @Xylvier's suggestion (thanks!) I wrote in the Kit-Ops support page and the developer explained to me that it is a function within the plug-in which can be turned of.
I suppose there is a recursive function which selects all the elements which are recognized as part of the main container object.